# Using AWS S3 Object Lifecycle, how can I delete old objects no created on the first of the month

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 for backups. I have it setup right now so that after 30 days objects are moved out to glacier for cold storage. Since these are backups what I would like to do is keep the last 30days of back-ups. Then after 30 days the backups taken on the first of each month. Then the after 1 year the backup taken on the first of the year.

Since A backup is made daily I need a way to tell AWS the following for lifecycle management.

1. If backup is more than 30 days old and not taken on the first of the month delete it.
2. If backup is more than 1 year old and not taken on the first of the month in the first month of the year delete it.

Right now I have to go in and clean house once a month. The reason I want to do this is that trying to keep every backup from every day get very storage intensive. How would I automate this process?